# RestOperations bean cannot be found

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I am trying to setup basic Auth for my spring boot project. So far, I've done this:

**CallAPI.java** in **com.app.apitool.RESTConsumer** package

```
public class CallAPI {

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

@Autowired
RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilderObj;

@Autowired
BasicAuthSetup basicAuthObj;

@Autowired
RestOperations rest;

String endpointURL = "";

public String pingAPi() {
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(basicAuthObj.getHeaders());

    ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.exchange(endpointURL, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

    System.out.println(response.getBody());
    return response.getBody();
}
}
```

**BasicAuthSetup.java** in **com.app.apitool.HTTPAuthSetup** package

```
@Component
public class BasicAuthSetup {
private String plainCreds = "id@account1:password";
private String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainCreds.getBytes());

@Bean
public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic" + base64Creds);
    System.out.println("Auth created: "+headers);
    return headers;
}                  
}
```

Upon running I get the following exception:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

> Field rest in com.appd.apitool.RESTConsumer.CallAPI required a bean of
>   type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' that could not be
>   found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' in your configuration.

I googled this error and I came across a similar (if not same) issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033872/required-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-web-client-restoperations-that-cou) and I'm following the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977634/spring-resttemplate-gives-401-unauthorized-error-when-sending-with-authorization?rq=1).

The reason I've decided to create a new issue is because I didn't see any solution mentioned in the post where the first link. Also, I'm new to spring-boot framework.

Main **App.java** in **com.app.apitool** package:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {

private static final Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);


@Autowired
private CallAPI callAPIobj;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/api")
public String testAPI() {
    return callAPIobj.pingAPi();
}

}
```

Comment: There is a lot of context missing here. How are you attempting to wire all this together? Java config? XML config? Can you show some of that? Also, showing the entire class, including the package definitions, etc.

Comment: @EricGreen I don't have any config file as this is a very bare-bones basic structure. I've never worked with spring framework before. I've added my main class above.

Comment: `RestOperations` is an interface implemented by [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), and you have auto-wired a **`RestTemplateBuilder`** for *creating* `RestTemplate` objects, so why do you believe you can auto-wire `RestOperations`? Use the builder. That's what it's for. --- Then again, you *also* have a `RestTemplate` field with a locally created instance, so why are you needing a `RestOperations`?

Comment: I get you. Are you running this in Maven?

Comment: @Andreas how do I do that in my case? Can you please write a sample code?

Comment: @EricGreen yes sir

Comment: @user2607744 Why did you wire in a `RestTemplateBuilder`? Why did you believe you needed to wire in a `RestOperations`? Why did you create a `RestTemplate` directly? The 3 actions seem to all be for the same purpose. What weird tutorial have you been following? Recheck your source material to see how it *should* be done.

Comment: Or just **read the documentation**, i.e. the **Spring Boot Reference Guide**, section [**33. Calling REST Services with RestTemplate**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-resttemplate.html), which shows that you wire in a `RestTemplateBuilder`, use it to build a `RestTemplate`, and then use that to execute a REST call.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the input but I am very new to spring framework. I'm following this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977634/spring-resttemplate-gives-401-unauthorized-error-when-sending-with-authorization?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so in your Maven project, your basic auth setup would be a good place for your bean configurations:

BasicAuthSetup.java:

```
package com.app.apitool.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Base64;

@Configuration
public class BasicAuthSetup {

    private static final String plainCreds = "id@account1:password";
    private static final  String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainCreds.getBytes());

    @Bean
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic" + base64Creds);

        return headers;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);

        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpEntity<String> stringHttpEntity() {
        return new HttpEntity<>(getHeaders());
    }
}
```

Then, create a test class under /src/main/java in the appropriate package as follows:

CallAPITest.java:

```
package com.app.apitool;

import com.app.apitool.config.BasicAuthSetup;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BasicAuthSetup.class)
public class CallAPITest {

    private static final String endpointURL = "";

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations rest;

    @Autowired
    private HttpEntity<String> stringHttpEntity;

    @Test
    public void pingAPi() {

        ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.exchange(endpointURL, HttpMethod.GET, stringHttpEntity, String.class);

        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        final String responseBody = response.getBody();

        assertNotNull(responseBody);
    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies you'll need in your Maven pom.xml for the above (change versions as you see fit):

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.9.6</jackson.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```